# How can I update an electron BrowserWindow icon after the window is already opened?

Tags: electron

With the electron api, I can set the window's icon when calling the BrowserWindow constructor, like this:

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    icon: __dirname + '/electric-glowing-bear.png');
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to update the icon after the fact. There seems to be a way to update the dock icon on Mac OS X, however, I am running Linux.

The purpose of this is so that I can 'badge' the icon with a number to indicate unread messages are waiting.

The only workaround I have found so far is to use a Tray icon, however, I would prefer to show the unread count in the dock / taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

You can set BrowserWindow icon when creating windows at like this.

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({icon: icon})
```

You can change BrowserWindow icon anytime like this.

```
mainWindow.setIcon(changeicon);
```

You can Taskbar icon overlay numbering anytime like this.

```
mainWindow.setOverlayIcon(overlayicon, description)
```

Windows overlay NativeImage - the icon to display on the bottom right corner of the taskbar icon. If this parameter is null, the overlay is cleared
description String - a description that will be provided to Accessibility screen readers
Sets a 16 x 16 pixel overlay onto the current taskbar icon, usually used to convey some sort of application status or to passively notify the user.

Comment: setOverlayIcon does not work on linux. Neither does mainWindow.setIcon.  Maybe it's been fixed since I tried before?  I'll test it again to find out.

Answer (score 1):

this should work as long as you have the appropriate files in place

```
const os = require('os'); // top of file
switch (os.platform()) {
    case 'darwin':
        mainWindow.setIcon('src/app/assets/icons/icon.icns');
        break;
    case 'win32':
        mainWindow.setIcon('src/app/assets/icons/icon.ico');
        break;
    default:
        mainWindow.setIcon('src/app/assets/icons/icon.png');
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this does not seem to be possible currently, at least not on Linux.